# scheduling a job every minute Rails 3.1 on Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, cron, scheduling, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I want to run a task every minute on Heroku to check if conditions are met to time-out certain user tasks.  I can only run a Heroku cron job every hour, so what's the best way to set up a timed task like this.  I am using Rails 3.1 on Heroku.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could use [delayed_job](https://github.com/tobi/delayed_job) with a self-restarting job with a `:run_at`. Something sort of like this:

```
class YourJob
    def do_interesting_things
        #... Do what needs to be done.
        self.delay(:run_at => 1.minute.from_now).do_interesting_things
    end

    def self.start_me_up
        new.do_interesting_things
    end
end
```

And then somewhere during your application's initialization:

```
YourJob.start_me_up
```

Comment: thank you - i will try that today and if it works i'll accept the answer :-)

Comment: Did this work out?  I'm needing to run a rake task every 1 minute and I'm thinking that there should be a way to make it run itself vs requiring cron.  Presently cron on heroku has a max of every hour.

Comment: @ylluminate: I never heard back but it should work, try it and let me know how it goes.

Comment: You should probably wrap the whole "do what needs to be done" in a big `begin`,`rescue` block or else your job won't restart if anything ever goes wrong.

Comment: @muistooshort i did this, but it looks like one of the workers is constantly running. i guess that is how sidekiq/delayedjob implements it?

Comment: @mingyeow: DJ usually has a `rake jobs:work` running in the background all the time, that's the process that looks for newly enqueued delayed jobs and runs them.

Comment: won't this recursive function lead to a stack overflow?

Comment: @mhz: The method isn't really recursive. The `delay` call adds an entry to the DelayedJob queue and DJ will call `do_interesting_things` when it scans the queue. So `do_interesting_things` isn't really calling itself, it is asking DJ to call itself later.

Comment: @muistooshort Thanks for the clarification

Comment: @muistooshort it doesn't work? I get an error of "uninitialized constant YourJob" should the method be defined `def self.do_interesting_things`?

Comment: @mhz: What is your class called? Presumably something more sensible than `YourJob`.

Comment: Its called `VrEmailJob`... though not sure why that would be a problem....? Its inheriting from ActiveJob::Base

Comment: @mhz Then why are you using `YourJob`? This answer is about delayed-job, you'll have to adapt it a little to use it with ActiveJob and you'll have to use the right class names.

Comment: @muistooshort I only said `YourJob` in the comment to put it in the context of this question... I'm not actually using `YourJob` in my code. I also spent too many hours trying to make delayed_jobs work, and now the jobs are disappearing mysteriously from my database. I'm going to throw in the towel here and try another solution, but thanks anyway.

Answer (score 9):

As of today, you can the scheduling gem, [clockwork](https://github.com/tomykaira/clockwork). Heroku officially supports this and you can find their documentation [here](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/clock-processes-ruby).

Comment: Just note that [clockwork](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/clock-processes-ruby) requires a dyno, so it will cost the same as any other type of dyno ($0.05 per hour, billable to the second -- about **$35/month**). Those who *don't* require scheduling "every minute", but are fine with *every 10 minutes*, *every hour*, or *every day (at a specific time)*, then consider the [Heroku Scheduler](https://addons.heroku.com/scheduler), a free add-on.

Comment: Another limitation of clockwork is that it can only run on a single dyno, so if you have more scheduled work than a single process can handle, the `delayed_job` solution will work better.

Answer (score 1):

Clockwork is the way to go but I will suggest another workaround.

Use scheduler (every 10min) + delayed jobs to execute the task every minute. This seems a little bit more reliable solution than the one without scheduler.

```
MyJob.run!

(1..8).each |i|
   MyJob.delay(run_at: i.minutes.from_now).run! # create 8 more jobs (each start 1 minute later)
end
```