# Does Rails Sleep() use concurrent connection?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

If our rails app is deployed to heroku and we use `sleep(2.minutes)` to queue a task, does this hog a connection or memory or something else?

I'm asking because heroku has limitations on concurrent connections. What if 25 users call the `sleep(2.minutes)` method, would this use up 25 concurrent connections for the next `2 minutes`?

Comment: Calling `sleep` inside a Rails app is going to cause huge problems because it will jam up the process like you theorized.

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest to look into using an ActiveJob to queue this task. Check out Resque or Sidekiq. Also check out http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_job_basics.html. This will be a more "Rails" way of doing it.

Try `YourJob.set(wait: 2.minutes).perform_later()`

Comment: But if it is a time critical task, then wouldn't active job be less accurate? As waiting 2 min is not the same as sleep for 2 mins. I believe in active job, it waits for 2 mins and then if the process is free executes it, else keeps waiting in the queue.

Comment: I believe doing perform as opposed to perform_later can help with this issue.

Comment: still, i think since active job is a part of rails, and runs on the same process as that of rails. There might be some kind of difference. I'm not sure of it. It's just something i hear and read some while back. I don't have any reference to corroborate the fact.

Comment: @Alfie this SO question suggests `delayed_job`. Is that a feasible alternative? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7315998/scheduling-a-job-every-minute-rails-3-1-on-heroku

Comment: I believe delayed_job works in a similar way. It stores it's scheduled jobs in a queue in a table in your db. But it's still the same process that run's your tasks.

Comment: Since you are running it on heroku. You might want to look into `heroku clock process`. I haven't used it till now, so i won't be much help regarding it further.