# Ruby on Rails execute recurring task

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, sidetiq

I need to perform a task roughly every 1 minute on my rails application. So far I have tried delayed job ([scheduling a job every minute Rails 3.1 on Heroku](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7315998/scheduling-a-job-every-minute-rails-3-1-on-heroku)) with no success (runs only the one time and then stopped) and right now I'm trying with Sidetiq gem (https://github.com/endofunky/sidetiq).

I have installed the gem and created the file

```
/config/initializers/sidetiq_test.rb
```

here's the code that I put inside:

```
class MyWorker
  include Sidekiq::Worker
  include Sidetiq::Schedulable

  recurrence { hourly.minute_of_hour(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60) }

  def perform
    p '####################################'
    p 'clients'
  end
end
```

I will perform some task in the official version but now I just insterted couple of prints.
I have restarted the server, no errors but nothing happens, do you know what am I missing?

One last note: the solution must be heroku compatible, because I don't have access to the crontab.

Answer (score 0):

More than one solution for this, but one thing you could use is clockwork for scheduling your sidekiq recurring task. It's a simple setup and easy to use: https://github.com/tomykaira/clockwork